# Counting posts in a nested loop based on a date

Tags: python, json, pandas, for-loop

I need to calculate the number of posts that have been published today/yesterday/a week ago/month ago, extracting the dates in unix format from a json-dict. Count the sum by id and make a table from it.

However, I have spent a lot of time figuring it out.

> Here is the code so far:

```
posts_today = []

posts_yesterday = []
posts_week = []
posts_month = []
user_posted = []


today = pd.Timestamp('today')
yesterday = (pd.Timestamp('today')- pd.Timedelta(days=1))
week_ago = (pd.Timestamp('today') - pd.Timedelta(weeks=1))
month_ago = (pd.Timestamp('today') - pd.Timedelta(weeks=4))
```

The loop for a month itself:

```
for user_id in list(wall_pickle.keys())[0:100]:
    for i in wall_pickle[user_id]['items']:

        if ((pd.to_datetime(i['date']*10e8)) >= month_ago):
            user_posted.append(user_id)
            posts_month.append(1)

    print(user_id,len(posts_month))
```

### That produces

That produces:

```
6932 6<br>
6984 6<br>
7074 6<br>
7141 6<br>
13456 6<br>
13467 6<br>
19226 6<br>
30365 11<br>
43713 31<br>
44611 31<br>
58972 42<br>
73013 43<br>
74905 44<br>
75089 45<br>
84090 47<br>
86882 47<br>
125789 47<br>
128317 47<br>
137443 66<br>
147006 85<br>
164366 85<br>
165490 95<br>
...
```

The left column is the id, the left is the count, however it becomes cumulative somehow.

The JSON scheme looks the following: `wall_pickle.keys()` are user ids and each of the id has a list `['items']` with a key `['date']`

Please guys help me out!

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer myself. Not pythonic, nor cool, but it wors fast on ~41K uids with 20 post deep.

```
posts_today = []
posts_3_days = []
posts_week = []
posts_month = []

today = pd.Timestamp(2018,1,26,0,0,0) 
three_days_ago = (pd.Timestamp(2018,1,26,0,0,0)- pd.Timedelta(days=3))
week_ago = (pd.Timestamp(2018,1,26,0,0,0) - pd.Timedelta(weeks=1))
month_ago = (pd.Timestamp(2018,1,26,0,0,0) - pd.Timedelta(weeks=4))

for user_id in list(wall_pickle.keys()):
    for i in wall_pickle[user_id]['items']:

        if ((pd.to_datetime(i['date']*10e8)) >= today):
            posts_today.append(user_id)
        if ((pd.to_datetime(i['date']*10e8)) >= three_days_ago):
            posts_3_days.append(user_id)
        if ((pd.to_datetime(i['date']*10e8)) >= week_ago):
            posts_week.append(user_id)
        if ((pd.to_datetime(i['date']*10e8)) >= month_ago):
            posts_month.append(user_id)
```

It produces a list of uids occured during matching - if X uid has 3 posts within the period of a week, that the loop will add X uid 3 times.
It looks shit, but it is super convenient since then you can `.value_counts()` and you get a `dict` that you can map over the `dataframe`.

Something like this:

```
# make a proper dataframe and save
posts_today = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(posts_today).value_counts())
posts_today.reset_index(inplace=True)
posts_today.columns=['user_id','daily_posts']
posts_today.to_csv(RAW+'posts_today.csv', index=False)
# the dict itself
posts_today_dict = pd.Series(posts_today['daily_posts'].values,
                             index=posts_today['user_id']).to_dict()
```

... etc.